# Get path to .xcframework programmatically at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have embedded a library and need to get it's file path.

I have tried accessing it using the library identifier and the bundle returned is nil.

I have also tried recursively showing all files in the main bundle and it's not there.

I have tried using .allFrameworks and .allBundles but mine isn't in the list.

The library is working and I can access its methods at runtime so I know it's loaded somewhere.

How can I get the path of that xcframework?

Answer (score 2):

`xcframework` are a tool for linking, once you have a resulting app bundle you don't find them in your app. Depending on the `xcframework` content, you  either find a normal framework in your app bundle, or no additional files at all if the `xcframework` contains static libraries. The later get merged into your app's binaries.

So you cannot find the `.xcframework` at runtime. You might find a `.framework` in your app bundle, though.

Comment: If that's relevant, the xcframework contains c++ files and headers which I'm bridging to reach in the swift code. But I assume your answer still stands. I understand this as "you're SOL", am I correct?

Comment: I didn't know they can contain source files. If so, they're probably going to get compiled into the target that "links" the `xcframework`. Header files won't get included anyway. But your question and comment suggest that it's actually some other problem you're trying to solve: why do you want the framework's path at runtime? If there's some resources you want to access, those should still get bundled and you should be able to find them.

Comment: It's a custom library that needs the path of its own location to work. Don't ask me why, I need to pass it as a param.